# ocorrencia de palavra na consulta sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Tenho uma consulta `SELECT NOME FROM PESSOA WHERE CODIGO = 1`

Ela me retorna  `ANA ANA JOAO ANA ALBERTO ANA`

Existe um modo de contar as ocorrencias da ana?

Usando apenas a consulta do sql?

Comment: select count(*) from pessoa where codigo = 1 and nome = 'ANA'

Comment: @JhonatanJorgedeLima: O que contém a coluna CODIGO? Ela é a chave primária da tabela PESSOA? // A consulta que postou como exemplo retornou uma única linha com os nomes ou várias linhas, cada uma com um nome? // Qual é o COLLATE da coluna NOME?

Comment: @Jhonatan, a coluna NOME contém somente uma única palavra? Poderia explicar melhor o contexto? A descrição me parece muito vaga.

Comment: Amigos este é so um exemplo, a consulta  acima trás literalmente essa escrita por completa no campo "ana ana joao ana alberto ana" ,- retorna uma unica linha com estas informação, realmente esta em um único campo, nao é retornada varias linhas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Existe um modo de contar as ocorrencias da ana* (...) *usando apenas a consulta do sql?*
>   *o meu select retorna apenas uma linha e uma coluna e nesse campo vem essa string literalmente como conteudo "ANA ANA JOAO ANA ALBERTO ANA"*

Jhonatan, considerando-se as explicações adicionais, me parece que a solução é quebrar o conteúdo da coluna NOME em *tokens*, utilizando função do tipo *split string*, e então contabilizar o número de ocorrências do *token*.

```
-- código #2 v3
with unpPESSOA as (
SELECT S.Item as Token
  from PESSOA as P
       cross apply dbo.SplitStrings_Moden (replace(P.NOME, ' ', '\'), '\') as S
  where P.CODIGO = 1
)
SELECT Token, count(*) as Qtd
  from unpPESSOA
  where Token = 'ANA' 
  group by Token;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No código #2 foi utilizada a função *split string* SplitStrings_Moden, disponível no artigo 
[Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

Caso haja mais de um espaço entre *tokens*, é necessário transformá-los em um único espaço, usando função do tipo Alltrim.

---

O código #2 pode ser facilmente alterado para permitir a contabilização do número de ocorrências de cada *token* em cada linha da tabela:

```
-- código #3
with unpPESSOA as (
SELECT CODIGO, S.Item as Token
  from PESSOA as P
       cross apply dbo.SplitStrings_Moden (replace(P.NOME, ' ', '\'), '\') as S
)
SELECT CODIGO, Token, count(*) as Qtd
  from unpPESSOA
  group by CODIGO, Token;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Para aprofundar no tema, sugiro a leitura do artigo “[Separar conteúdo de texto multivalorado (string split)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/01/27/separar-conteudo-de-texto-multivalorado_string-split/)”.